# How can i remove a specified field from all documents of a collection using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to remove  key "passwrod" from all documents from users collection using mongoose , is it possible to do it using $unset ?

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("58ec890c91b2b612084fd827"),
        "username" : "zain",
        "passwrod" : 123,
        "password" : 8 },
{   "_id" : ObjectId("58ec8918364116187845948d"),
        "username" : "bob",
        "password" : 123,
        "passwrod" : 12  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ec890c91b2b612084fd827"), "username" : "zain", "passwrod" : 123, "password" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ec8918364116187845948d"), "username" : "bob", "password" : 123, "passwrod" : 12 }
```

Query:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":1}})
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ec890c91b2b612084fd827"), "username" : "zain", "password" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ec8918364116187845948d"), "username" : "bob", "password" : 123 }
```

Comment: {$unset:{"passwrod":1}} , what does this 1 stands for?

Comment: it is not mandatory, you can use "" also, and it doesn't impact the operation
check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/ for more details

Comment: db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":1}})
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":2}})
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":""}})
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":null}})
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$unset:{"passwrod":"abcd"}})
all are valid